# Excel VBA - SQL Query Error: Operation is not allowed when the object is closed

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I have a VBA script that makes a call to SSMS to run a query and paste the results into Excel.  I have this same code used for 2 other queries prior to this one and they both work, but this one gives the error for some reason.

I originally thought it was due to the Temp tables, so I added "set nocount on" to the beginning, but it didn't help.  Any tips or recommendations are appreciated!

Error Message:

**Run-time error '3704':**

**Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.**

```
Sub Test()

'Setup variables
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim StrQuery As String
Dim SOURCE As String
Dim DATABASE As String
Dim QUERY As String
Dim intColIndex As Integer

'Assign variables
SOURCE = [Data Source]
DATABASE = [Database]

QUERY = "set nocount on"
QUERY = QUERY + " declare @Variable1 int"
QUERY = QUERY + " declare @Variable2 int"
QUERY = QUERY + " declare @Variable3 datetime"
QUERY = QUERY + " declare @Variable4 datetime"
QUERY = QUERY + " select @Variable1 = [xxxx]"
QUERY = QUERY + " select @Variable2=(select Field1 from Table1 where Field2 = @Variable1)"
QUERY = QUERY + " select @Variable3=min(Variable3) from Table2 where Field3=@Variable2"
QUERY = QUERY + " select @Variable4=max(Field4) from Table2 where Field3=@Variable2"
QUERY = QUERY + " select distinct b.Field5, b.Field10 into #Temp1"
QUERY = QUERY + " from Table3 p(nolock)"
QUERY = QUERY + " inner join Table4 b(nolock) on b.Field5 = p.fkField5"
QUERY = QUERY + " inner join Table5 cp (nolock) on cp.Field6 = p.Field11"
QUERY = QUERY + " where Field3=@Variable2 "
QUERY = QUERY + " select Field3,Field9,Variable3,Field4 into #Temp2 from Table2 cf (nolock)"
QUERY = QUERY + " inner join Table6 ac (nolock) on ac.Field7=cf.Field3"
QUERY = QUERY + " where Variable3 >= @Variable3 - 365 and Field4 < @Variable4 + 1"
QUERY = QUERY + " and ac.Field8 <>4"
QUERY = QUERY + " select distinct cp.Field3,Field9,convert(varchar(10),Variable3,101) Variable3,convert(varchar(10),Field4,101) Field4"
QUERY = QUERY + " from Table5 cp (nolock)"
QUERY = QUERY + " inner join Table3 p (nolock) on p.Field11=cp.Field6"
QUERY = QUERY + " inner join Table4 b (nolock) on b.Field5 = p.fkField5"
QUERY = QUERY + " inner join #Temp1 bb on bb.Field5=b.Field5"
QUERY = QUERY + " inner join #Temp2 oth on oth.Field3=cp.Field3"
QUERY = QUERY + " drop table #Temp1"
QUERY = QUERY + " drop table #Temp2"

'Run the query and paste results into Cell X11 on the first tab of the workbook
    ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & SOURCE & "; Initial Catalog=" & DATABASE & "; Integrated Security=SSPI;"

    cnn.Open ConnectionString

    cnn.CommandTimeout = 900

    StrQuery = QUERY

    rst.Open StrQuery, cnn

    Sheets(1).Range("X11").CopyFromRecordset rst
'Add the column headers
For intColIndex = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
    Range("X10").Offset(0, intColIndex).Value = rst.Fields(intColIndex).Name
Next 

End Sub
```